# Can we get a stack trace for strict refs violations in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am using `use strict` in my Perl program, but the errors aren't as helpful as they could be since they just list the single offending line. Is there a way to get backtraces when use strict fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `strict` pragma contains the categories `subs` which forbids barewords, and `vars` which requires you to declare all variables. Those are *compile-time* errors. A stack trace for these is not helpful, as they directly stem from the source code on that line.

The `strict` category `refs` forbids strings as references, which is a *runtime error*. Here a stacktrace may be helpful to figure out where that string came from.

One way to get a stack trace is to [`use Carp::Always`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Always) (or as a command line flag: `-MCarp::Always`). This modifies all errors and warnings to include a stack trace. Because it makes all errors much longer, is best to only use this as a debugging help.

If you're having the problem that your subroutines are getting invalid arguments, it may be better to validate the inputs. E.g.:

```
use Carp;

sub foo {
  my ($ref) = @_;

  # dies from the line where "foo()" was called
  croak q(Argument "ref" must be a scalar reference)
    unless ref $ref eq 'SCALAR' or ref $ref eq 'REF';

  do_something_with($$ref);
}
```

When using one of the functions from `Carp` (e.g. `croak()` or `confess()`) you can force a stack trace by adding the Perl option `-MCarp=verbose`.

Comment: `Carp::cluck` and `Carp::confess` always output the stack trace.